# NSTokenFieldDelegate called with 'Wj'

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I programmatically created a NSTokenField and set a delegate. I even tried setting the current `.stringValue` to an empty string before adding it to any subviews, but as soon as I add the token field to a view (even before it's focused) it calls the delegates

```
-(id)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField representedObjectForEditingString:(NSString *)editingString
```

method 2 times with `Wj` as editingString.

The code for creating the token field is straight forward

```
NSTokenField *tokenField = [[NSTokenField alloc] init];

tokenField.stringValue = @"";
tokenField.delegate = self;

self.tokenField = tokenField;
```

Why is the delegate called with `Wj`? I'd guess there is an error in NSTokenField, but I couldn't find anything using google and it seems as I'm the only one experiencing this, so it might as well be an error on my side.

Here's a screenshot of the backtrace:

[image]

Comment: Is `tokenField` in the delegate method the same address as `self.tokenField`?

Comment: Just tried it and yes, they both are the same :/

Comment: Did you search the project for "Wj"? What happens if you don't set the delegate?

Comment: There is no 'Wj' in the whole project and if I don't set the delegate, the method isn't called at all :/

I've updated the question to include a screenshot of the backtrace (when the delegate is set and the method is called)

Comment: I tried your code. No delegate method is called and the token field is invisible, its size is 0.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding the NSTokenField to a NSGridView, which uses AutoLayout. I'm guessing without a NSGridView/AutoLayout, it should work by using `[[NSTokenField alloc] initWithFrame:rect]` and specifying a rect.

Comment: Yes, I see the token field when I specify a rect but the delegate method is not called. Is the token field in the gridview displaying a value?

Comment: No, it doesn't display a value.. Which macOS version are you using? Mine's macOS 10.13.3 (17D47)

Comment: Apparently `-NSTextField _baselineOffsets` sends `setStringValue:@"Wj"` to the cell.

Comment: Did you align the baseline of the tokenfield? This is a bug, reproducable in a small test app. The gridview doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: You are absolutely right! My NSGridView has the row alignment mode NSGridRowAlignmentFirstBaseline, when using no row alignment, the delegate isn't called :)